# javascript string word wrap on matches in another string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

If I have a certain string input, that I want to compare to another string and wrap matches of the input string whithin the other string using the largest possible match.  How would I best wrap the matches in a  tag?  This is a non-trivial question.

Basically, I want to match an entered string with another string, using a span tag to show matched portions of the target found in the entered string.

- Match from start of input string first (largest possible match)
- Partial match of a search word should be highlighted (see "barge", "barges" in example)
- Special character breaks should match "fred/dred" entered would be two words.
- The input string will vary depending upon what the users input.
- Match the input string from the start as a priority
- Match each word where it occurs

if the user enters a string with multiple words, I want to wrap matches of them incrementally starting from the beginning where they occur in a second string.  They might or might not have spaces at the start/end of the string that is entered.  I would want the largest portion to be wrapped.

Example input strings:

```
"Brown cats cannot be white cats"
"blue pigs "
"large, charged/marged barge pigs"
```

I would want them wrapped as so:

```
"<span class='wrapper'>Brown cats cannot be white cats</span>"
```

in the destination string where matches occur, even partial but with the largest possible match wrapped.

Example of a string to wrap:

```
"Hi bill, brown cats cannot be white cats and cows are not blue pigs, blue melons are large but not batteries charged barges with white cats carry coal"
```

Final string for each example input:

```
"Hi bill, <span class='wrapper'>brown cats cannot be white cats</span> and cows are not blue pigs, blue melons are large but not batteries charged barges with <span class='wrapper'>white cats</span> carry coal"

"Hi bill, brown cats cannot be white cats and cows are not <span class='wrapper'>blue pigs</span>, blue melons are large but not batteries charged barges with white cats carry coal"

"Hi bill, brown cats cannot be white cats and cows are not blue <span class='wrapper'>pigs</span>, blue melons are large but not batteries <span class='wrapper'>charged</span> <span class='wrapper'>barge</span>s with white cats carry coal"
```

Possible matches for: "Brown cats cannot be white cats"

```
"Brown cats cannot be white cats"
"Brown cats cannot be white"
"Brown cats cannot be"
"Brown cats cannot"
"Brown cats"
"Brown"
"Brown" "cats" "cannot" "be" "white" "cats"
```

If I were to simply wrap each matched word I could do:

```
function replaceWords(wordsy, text) {
   var re = '(' + wordsy + ')(?![^<]*(?:<\/script|>))',
       regExp = new RegExp(re, 'ig'),
       sTag = "<span class='wrapper'>",
       eTag = "</span>";
   return text.replace(regExp, sTag + '$&' + eTag);
};
var matchstring = "Brown cats cannot be white cats";
var wrapstring = "Hi bill, brown cats cannot be white cats and cows are not blue pigs, blue melons are large but not batteries charged barges with white cats carry coal";
var words = myValue.split(" ");
var i = words.length; while (i--) {
    wrapstring = replaceWords(words[i], wrapstring );
};
```

That does not satisfy the requirement for "largest match".  I would want the largest possible match of any portion of the matchstring that occurs in the wrapstring.

Solutions using pure javascript or jquery or a combo are acceptable.

**EDIT:**  Some have suggested KMP, here is example of KMP [jsfiddle.net/y5yJY/2](http://jsfiddle.net/y5yJY/2) but it does not, it its current form fit all criterial and does a single match.

Comment: See my answer for one possible partial solution (improved on my question code)

Comment: Any feedback on my code? Is that what you were after?

Comment: Added note on KMP for those interested.

Answer (score 3):

I've got an interesting solution which should work as your original spec. It hasn't been stress tested, I'm not sure if you want to process a large amount of text or not, and it does quite a few regular expression matches. Not necessarily the cleanest or simplest solution, but it works an intended.

**Features and limitations:**

- It handles most odd cases in the match string, such as repeated words, very similar or repeated phrases, etc.
- At the moment you can't reliably have `[` and `]` characters in the source string, as they're used internally. If it's a problem, you have to swap them to any other character or character combination before matching.
- For a match string of `N` words, `2*N + 5` string replaces are done using regular expressions of varying complexity.
- It matches the words and phrases case-insensitive, ignoring any non-word characters. At the same time, it preserves mixed-case words and non-word characters in the result.

**How it works:**

1. First, it looks for every word separately, and appends their index in the match string to them in square brackets: `word[2]`. If the word appears multiple times, it appends all indices: `word[3][2][1]`.
2. Next, it finds and marks words that are not on wrapping boundaries by looking at the indices of the surrounding words. In a separate step, it removes the indices from those words. In the end `one[1] two[2] three[3]` will become `one[1] []two three[3]`.
3. All that's left now is to do some assumptions in a certain order, and wrap the words/phrases. Have a look at the code to see all the replaces that's done.

It is important, that after step one, we never match the words directly, from then on a word is just refered to as `any number of word characters before [index]` or `any number of word characters after []`. This makes sure we wrap repeating words/phrases correctly.

Have a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7rTSw/3/). I have added a hover effect, so you can see what words are grouped and wrapped together.

And here's the crazy code, enjoy!

```
var matchstring = 'Brown cats cannot be white cats';
var wrapstring = 'Hi bill, brown cats cannot be white cats and cows are not blue pigs, blue melons are large but not batteries charged barges with white cats carry coal, and the word "cannot" should match ';

// Pre-process matchstring to make it a flat list of words
// separated by single spaces.
matchstring = matchstring.replace(/\W+/g,' ');

var wrapStart = '<span class="wrapped">';
var wrapEnd = '</span>';

var matcharray = matchstring.split(' ');
var i, reg;

// Mark all matched words with indices
// one -> one[1]
for (i = 0; i < matcharray.length; i++) {
    reg = new RegExp('\\b' + matcharray[i] + '\\b', 'ig');
    wrapstring = wrapstring.replace(reg, '$&[' + i + ']');
}

// Mark all inner words
// one[1] two[2] three[3] -> one[1] []two[2] three[3]
for (i = 1; i < matcharray.length; i++) {
    reg = new RegExp('\\b(\\w+)([\\]\\d\\[]*\\[' + (i - 1) + '\\][\\]\\d\\[]*)(\\W+)(\\w+)([\\]\\d\\[]*\\[' + i + '\\][\\]\\d\\[]*)(?=\\W+\\w+[\\[\\d\\]]*\\[' + (i + 1) + '\\])', 'ig');
    wrapstring = wrapstring.replace(reg, '$1$2$3[]$4$5');
}

// Remove indices from inner words
// one[1] []two[2] three[3] -> one[1] []two three[3]
wrapstring = wrapstring.replace(/\[\](\w+)[\[\d\]]*/g, '[]$1');

// Start tags
// one[1] []two three[3] -> {one []two three[3]
wrapstring = wrapstring.replace(/(\w+)\[[\[\d\]]+\](\W+)\[\]/g, wrapStart + '$1$2[]');

// End tags
// {one []two three[3] -> {one []two three}
wrapstring = wrapstring.replace(/\[\](\w+\W+\w+)\[[\[\d\]]+\]/g, '$1' + wrapEnd);

// Wrap double words
// one[1] two[2] -> {one two}
wrapstring = wrapstring.replace(/(\w+)\[[\[\d\]]+\](\W+\w+)\[[\[\d\]]*\]/g, wrapStart + '$1$2' + wrapEnd);

// Orphan words
// unmatched matched[1] unmatched -> unmatched {matched} unmatched
wrapstring = wrapstring.replace(/(\w+)\[[\[\d\]]+\]/g, wrapStart + '$1' + wrapEnd);

// Remove left-over tags
// []word -> word
wrapstring = wrapstring.replace(/\[\]/g, '');

alert(wrapstring);
```

### Matching partial words

As previously mentioned, after the first step words are only processed by their appended indices. This means if we want to do some clever matching instead of just whole words, we just need to modify the regex in the first `for` loop. This is the piece of code with which we will fiddle in this section:

```
reg = new RegExp('\\b' + matcharray[i] + '\\b', 'ig');
```

The `\b` in the regex means match word boundaries, i.e. beginning or end of a sequence of word characters. That's why the above `\bword\b` regex only gives us whole words, as `word` needs to be surrounded by word boundaries. But it doesn't have to be this way.

If we want to match all words in the text beginning with our keyword, we can change the above line to the following:

```
reg = new RegExp('\\b' + matcharray[i] + '\\w*\\b', 'ig');
```

This results in the regex `\bword\w*\b`. It matches all `word` character sequences followed by 0 or more further word characters (`\w*`), surrounded by word boundaries. Note that backslashes need to be escaped within javascript strings (`\\` means a single `\`).

Depending on requirements, we can easily create further regex combinations:

- `\bword\w*\b` matches words beginning with a keyword.
- `\b\w*word\b` matches words ending with a keyword.
- `\b\w*word\w*\b` matches words containing a keyword.
- `\b(\w*word|word\w*)\b` matches words ending or beginning with a keyword.

You can even say that you only want to match minor modifications of a words. For example `\b\w{0,2}word\w{0,2}\b` will only match a word if it has at most a two letter prefix and/or suffix. So `danger` will match `endanger`, `cat` will match `cats`, but `can` won't match `cannot`, as that would be 3 extra letters.

Matching complex plural forms and irregular verbs is not easy, you could build a massive dictionary of irregular words on your server and pre-process the word, so if the user enters `foot`, using the regex `\b(foot|feet)\b` will match both forms. An easier solution would be to only care about regular words. For most words, matching `\bword(s|es|)\b` will be enough to catch plurals, it matches `word`, `words` and `wordes` as well. For words like `fly`, the regex `\bfl(y|ies)\b` will do the job. For words like `index`, the regex `\bind(ex|exes|ices)\b` will match most common forms.

As I'm not really a language expert, I'll just leave it at that for now.

### Wildcards in input

Similarly to the above, it's very easy to add support for wildcards in the input string. Say we want to let the user enter `?` to mean *any character*. If the input is `?red`, we just need to replace `?` with `\w` in our regex. For example `\b\wred\b` will match `fred` and `dred` as well.

Just like the above, you can also use multiple wildcards, replace them with `\w+` for *one or more characters* or `\w*` for *zero or more characters*. `\bf\w+d\b` will match `fed` and `feed`, `\w*` will match `fd` too.

Comment: This is quite close to my desired result however it has a challenge in your test with "Hi bill, brown cats cannot be white cats" as the search string - 'bill,' is not highlighted for some reason.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss: As I mentioned, the input string is assumed to be a list of words separated by single spaces, that's why it didn't match `bill,`. I have updated my code to pre-process the search string, so now it accepts anything, and my code replaces multiple non-word characters with single spaces to get the desired input. I have also updated the demo.

Comment: First off, thank you for your efforts, this is pretty close although it does not support bullet two - partial words entered. For instance "hi, bil, rown cats cannot be white cat cow" does not match and hightlight "bil", "rown", "cat" and "cow" as those are partial words found in the searched text.  I do like where this is going however.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss: I have elaborated a bit on partial word matching and wildcard support, they are very easy to add actually. See the last two sections in my edited post.

Answer (score 1):

What about this: (describes algorithm only, not written in code)

Imagine you have the two strings written out on two sheets of paper. Place the two sheets so that one is above the other. Move the top sheet off to the left, so that its last letter is on top of the bottom sheet's first letter. Now, do the two overlapping letters match? If so, you have a match of length 1. Record that as your longest match. Then, move the top sheet one character to the right. Now two letters overlap. Do they match? If so, you have a max match of size 2. Keep moving the top sheet over 1 character to the right, and each time, find the largest section of matched, overlapping characters. Always keep track of your biggest match. Keep going until your top sheet is so far over to the right that its first character overlaps with the other sheet's last character.

I don't know how easy this would be to implement in javascript, but as an algorithm, I think it is sound.

PS- for the bit where you need to find the "largest section of matched, overlapping characters", you could do something like this:

```
/* Note: str1 and str2 are the two overlapping portions of the strings */
var largestMatch = 0;
var currMatch = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    if (str1[i] == str2[i]) currMatch++;
    else currMatch = 0;
    largestMatch = Math.max(largestMatch, currMatch);
}
// largestMatch is the size of the largest section of matched characters
```

Comment: This did give me some ideas :) +1 for that

Comment: The algorithm is good because it's simple, but has complexity `O(nm)` which is slow. I recommend a simple adaptation of KMP, which is perfect for this case, and has linear runtime complexity.

Comment: Added note/example of KMP in question text.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to address this: (looking for improvement as it is not perfect)
(this is wrapped in a jQuery document ready)
as here:http://jsfiddle.net/KvM47/

```
function findStringLimit(searchChar, searchCharIndex, searchedString) {
    return searchedString.substring(0, searchedString.lastIndexOf(searchChar, searchCharIndex));
};

function replaceWords(wordsy, text) {
    var re = '(' + wordsy + ')(?![^<]*(?:<\/script|>))',
        regExp = new RegExp(re, 'ig'),
        sTag = "<span class='wrappedWord'>",
        eTag = "</span>";
    return text.replace(regExp, sTag + '$&' + eTag);

};
var longstring = $('#mystring');
var htmlString =longstring .html(); //  instance html
myValue = "Brown cats cannot be white cats";
myValue = myValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");//trim whitespace at each end

var words = myValue.split(" ");
var allPhrases = [];
allPhrases.push(myValue);

var i = words.length;
while (i--) {
    allPhrases.push(findStringLimit(" ", allPhrases[(words.length - i) - 1].length, allPhrases[(words.length - i) - 1]));
};

var i = allPhrases.length;
while (i--) {
    if (allPhrases[i] != "") words = words.concat(allPhrases[i]);
};
var i = words.length;
while (i--) {
    htmlString = replaceWords(words[i], htmlString);
};
longstring.html(htmlString);
```

Things to improve:

- use other characters to separate words, not just spaces.
- make it more efficient
- better detection of "chunks" of strings (two or more words together) in the "search" and "matched" strings and handle those as well.

Comment: If runtime is an issue, I suggest looking into implementing KMP or one of the other linear string search algorithms. They would be **much** faster.

Comment: Hmm... It seems to wrap all words, nesting as well.

Comment: @davin - good thought, and I DO have the KMP algorithm in JavaScript that I can test with as well.

Comment: here is example of KMP http://jsfiddle.net/y5yJY/2/ but it does not, it its current form fit all criterial and does a single match.

Comment: @Mark, KMP is incredibly flexible. I don't have much time right now, although I made a few small changes to your implementation, and it now matches more than one item (I didn't do thorough testing, so there might be small bugs): http://jsfiddle.net/y5yJY/3/ It's actually pretty cool :)

Comment: @davin, some error on the fiddle page somewhere.  If I get a chance later I will try to figure out what makes it not run on the button click.

Comment: @Mark, you might be using a browser that doesn't support `Array.map`, I'll stick in a quick implementation and check again.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/y5yJY/4/ and let me know. Works for me in Chrome, FF and IE9. Although then again, so did the previous link. Are you by any chance using IE8 or less?

Comment: No error now, but produces same result as original - single match on the pattern entered - 'cats and cows coal' should match all those words, anywhere, unless I misunderstood your attempt (not studied it yet...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. Type in "cats" and see if that does what it's supposed to...?

Comment: At the moment it doesn't highlight partial matches (not too difficult to implement), but it certainly highlights multiple complete matches...

Comment: yep, single term matches instances. Now need to modify to match my criteria as listed :) good progress though! See the bullet list near the start of the question for criteria and examples for illustration.