# Highlight chunks of text with background-color

Tags: javascript, html

I've written some code that highlights portions of text in yellow upon click and drag. Users can also remove their highlights when they click the "Clear" button. However, my code appears buggy. It does not highlight large sections of text (e.g., multiple sentences), especially if someone wants to highlight things quickly, although it nonetheless console.logs the selected sections as desired.

Also oddly, if you highlight 1 letter, then all letters that are the same are highlighted.

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix this highlighting issue? My goal is that users can highlight as much text as they'd like and without bugginess.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<style>
    #removeHighlight {
      margin: 50px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu eum eros vitae persequeris, laudem possit nam ex. Labore eloquentiam per an. Sit ex omnesque interpretaris, habeo tantas eos ad, ea eos ludus inciderint. Facete tritani pro ei, vim evertitur liberavisse ex. Ridens indoctum
    duo cu, est utamur aliquando expetendis ne. Cum nusquam definiebas ex, id esse neglegentur cum, eu libris bonorum volumus vis. Ius et quis omnis graeco, no his nullam perpetua dissentiet. No vix possim scripserit consequuntur, te mnesarchum philosophia
    sed. Ne mea putent iudicabit, in eam ipsum viris dicunt. Eum amet accommodare ex, sint malis adversarium at qui.
  </div>
  <div><button id="removeHighlight" style="color:green">Clear</button></div>

  <script>
    function getSelectedText() {
      var text = "";
      if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
      } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type == "Text") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
      }
      return text;
    }

    function doSomethingWithSelectedText() {
      var selectedText = getSelectedText();
      if (selectedText) {
        var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
        var selectedTextRegExp = new RegExp(selectedText.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'), 'g');
        contentDiv.innerHTML = contentDiv.innerHTML.replace(selectedTextRegExp, '<span style="background-color: yellow;">$&</span>');
        console.log(selectedTextRegExp)
      }
    }

    document.onmouseup = doSomethingWithSelectedText;
    document.onkeyup = doSomethingWithSelectedText;

    function clearSelections() {
      var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
      contentDiv.innerHTML = contentDiv.innerHTML.replace(/<span style="background-color: yellow;">(.*?)<\/span>/g, '$1');
    }
    document.getElementById("removeHighlight").addEventListener("click", clearSelections);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest you update your jQuery version to one without security issues `jquery/2.1.1`  Just delete it since you are not using it?

Comment: Good point! Deleted and edited my post. Unfortunately, that did not fix the bugginess :(

Comment: All modern browsers default to JavaScript so you can remove the `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: FWIW this is a bit more difficult than it would seem at a glance so this is a good learning project.  For example if you highlight a set of word then re-highlight part of it you need to deal with the HTML wrap start/close of the span you are using; things like that

Comment: Somewhat old but still a similar concept https://stackoverflow.com/a/44007896/125981  This is WAY old and probably needs a better answer but still I remember a similar quest https://stackoverflow.com/q/6359540/125981

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the text in an HTML `<mark>` tag.

> The mark element represents a run of text in one document marked or
> highlighted for reference purposes, due to its relevance in another
> context.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-mark-element

```html
Example of <mark>marked</mark> text.
```

Comment: How much has changed since I first did something like this a million years ago the hard way :)